# The human brain in numbers II-A: synaptic connections per structural type

Tags: neuroscience, brain, literature, neuroanatomy, synapses

The overall number of synapses in the human brain is roughly 1,000 trillion, i.e. 10,000 synapses per neuron.

I assume that each [structural type of neuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron#Classification) (basket, pyramidal, ...) has a somehow characteristic average number of in-coming and out-going synaptic connections, i.e. not every type of neuron will have the same roughly 10,000 in-coming and 10,000 out-going synaptic connections.

> I am looking for a thorough overview of these characteristic numbers
>   by structural type.

Ideally as a link to an existing resource, but if someone with a good overview over the literature would take the effort  to compile such an overview (like user *another 'Homo sapien'* thankfully did in his answer to [The human brain in numbers I: neurons](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53587/the-human-brain-in-numbers-i-neurons)), it would be even greater.

What's for sure: such an overview will be a) not complete and b) only estimates, so don't worry about that.

Comment: Please don't keep reposting effectively the same question. This is almost identical to the one that was closed last.

Comment: Also, very importantly, we actually gave you some great resources on the last question you asked to follow up on, and you seemed entirely disinterested and expecting people here to do your work for you. I found that really rude actually. It's like you are going to StackOverflow and asking somebody to write you a sorting algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand your discontent.. I just ask for specific references which seems perfectly ok at other SE sites. "BRAIN project's web site" is not a specific reference in my humble opinion.

Comment: Concerning your first comment: I was explicitely advised to split up my question  (to make it less broad) and followed this advise. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Your new question is absolutely not any less broad than the last one, it just reflects a basic misunderstanding of neuron morphology. If you plan to make 2 more versions of this question, still asking the same question in different angles, those will also be too broad.

Comment: To give you an idea of what is acceptable, see something like https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57495/cortical-projections-from-layers-2-3-back-to-4/57519#57519 This is asking about just a single pathway, between two layers of cortex, only talking about excitatory cells, and I wrote a multiple page answer.

Comment: Would you please be so kind to correct my basic misunderstanding. Aren't synapses something one can count? And why shouldn't there be a difference in number between different morphological types of neurons? I just have no clue where my basic misunderstanding lies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62901/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-bryan-krause).